# Написание k8s Helm чартов и удобное тестирование

Tags: devops, kubernetes, helm

Я новичок в k8s.

**Сейчас:**

Сейчас имею k8s кластер с zero trust, соответственно, тестирую сразу на нем путем git push и ожидания деплоя через gitlab ci. Очевидно, это не правильный путь.

**Хотелось бы:**

Деплой локально (minikube?), с возможностью быстро увидеть изменения (какой-нибудь hot reload для helm?). Поднятие локального кластера, который приближен к продуктивному (zero trust и прочие).

**Гуглил эту проблему, нашел:**

- https://skaffold.dev/
- https://github.com/garden-io/garden

**Суть:**

1. Прошу натолкнуть на правильное решение.
2. Могут ли утилиты выше помочь с этой проблемой?

Спасибо :)